# Datatables excel Export: Single Column type as text

Tags: jquery, datatables, export-to-excel

I have been working on datatables jquery plugin and on exporting the datatable to excel, numbers in a particular column are displayed in the exponential notation. How can i convert the data to text for one column only?

Comment: Have you expanded the column in sheet and checked if it has the proper values there?

Comment: yes it does, i want to display that one column as text only, otherwise values like 1283901284091820000 are displayed as 1.2839E+18

Comment: Can you link that file here?

Comment: Hey, Himanshu. Thanks for your help but i figured out my way around this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my way around this. Here is what I did

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
                dom: 'BLfrtip',
                pageLength: 50,
                buttons: [{
                    extend: 'excel',
                    exportOptions: {
                        columns: ':visible'
                    },
                Text: 'Export To Excel',
                filename: 'Transaction Report',                      
                customizeData: function (data) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.body.length; i++) {
                       for (var j = 0; j < data.body[i].length; j++) {
                            if (data.header[j] == "Column Name") {
                                data.body[i][j] = '\u200C' + data.body[i][j];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }}]});
```

This adds double quotes to each entry in the column

Comment: Yes but when you try to copy the cell value and use it to do an SQL Query for example, that \u200c character is still there and the SQL will not find a match. How do we get around that?

Answer (score 0):

By using exportOptions property of jquery datatable plugin you can restrict columns from exporting.

```
$('#myTable').DataTable( {
  buttons: [
  {
    extend: 'excelHtml5',
    text: 'Save current page',
    exportOptions: {
     columns: 0,1,2 //it will exporting only 3 columns out of n no of columns
    }
  }
]
});
```

By using this you can avoid exporting of problematic column !!

Comment: I need that column, it is not a problematic column, please try and understand the issue